# How to iterate over each word in a Trie using __iter__()and __next__() functions and generators in Python

Tags: python, iterator, trie

I have a Trie that is structured below. I am trying to write an iterator and next function that will iterate over each word in the Trie and then raise StopIteration once it is completed but I'm struggling to understand how these two functions are supposed to work. I know that I need to use yield instead of simply returning but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it. Appreciate any help.

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.char = char
        self.children = {}
        self.is_word = False

class TrieDictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode("")

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # get next word from iterator and stop iteration if no more words
```

Comment: What does a non-empty trie look like? Those are the kinds of details `__next__` has to make use of.

Comment: The root node points to 26 other nodes (children) which are essentially each character in the alphabet. Then those point to other nodes and so forth filling out the tree until a word is formed, in which case is_word = True

Comment: So `__next__` has to keep track of which node is the "current" node: save a reference to it, update the current node, then return the saved reference (or a portion of it).

Comment: Basically, `__next__` (and thus `TrieDictionary`) has to track the state you would otherwise be tracking outside the class. (Often, a separate iterator class is used so that `TrieDictionary` doesn't have to track these details itself. `__iter__` returns a wrapper around `self` rather than `self` directly, and the other class implements `__next__`.)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a generator on the `TreeNode` class, then you don't really need to worry about `__next__`:

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.char = char
        self.children = {}
        self.is_word = False

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.is_word:
            yield ""
        for ch, child in self.children.items():
            for word in child:
                yield ch + word


class TrieDictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode("")

    def add(self, word):
        node = self.root
        for ch in word:
            if ch not in node.children:
                node.children[ch] = TrieNode(ch)
            node = node.children[ch]
        node.is_word = True
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.root

# demo     
tree = TrieDictionary()
tree.add("sensitive").add("sense").add("senior").add("sentiment").add("sensible")
print(*tree)
```